# Finding matrix M that transforms matrix A to the closest fit of matrix B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

$A$ and $B$ are known $4 \times n$ matrices, $n > 4$.
I need to find the $4 \times 4$ matrix $M$ which results in global minimum for the function sqrsum(($M \times A) - B$), where sqrsum is the sum of squared elements in the given matrix.

I thought I could find a numeric solution by calculating [the gradient for $M$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix) and iterating towards the minimum, but this approach might get stuck in a local minima. How can I find the best fit for $M$?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is equivalent to $\min_X f(X) = \|AX-B\|^2$ where $\|X\| = trace(XX^\top)$ is the Frobenius norm.

Notice that $f(X)$ is a quadratic convex function, hence an analytic solution is given by Newton's method.

Instead of iterating: $X_{n+1} = X_n - \nabla f(X_n)$, you iterate $X_{n+1}=X_n-\left(\nabla^2f(X)\right)^{-1}\nabla f(X)$.

Can you do it now ?